# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint in psql

Tags: psql

`Key (owner_id)=(0) already exists.`

Getting the above error relating to the owners table when I try to run both tables, although the first table is created fine on its own.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
DROP TABLE pet CASCADE;
DROP TABLE owner CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE pet(
pet_id SERIAL4 primary key,
pet_type varchar(255),
pet_name varchar(255),
pet_age INT2,
pet_weight INT4,
behaviour_score INT4
);

CREATE TABLE owners(
owner_id SERIAL4 primary key,
owner_name varchar(255),
owner_email varchar(255) 
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that both tables were in fact dropped completely before you attempted to run `CREATE TABLE` again?

Comment: Yes fairly sure that's the case or if they weren't I have definitely subsequently dropped them again before trying to run, but I continue to get the error.

Comment: Please use code formatting for your code in the post either by indenting with 4 spaces or use the code button (the one with the curly braces) to make your post even better readable. Thank you!

Comment: @Alba, what version of PostgreSQL are you running, I am unable to replicate this issue. Also, I doubt that it is the drop and create that is causing this error, unless an older or new version of psql than what I am using (9.3.x) handles sequences as identity columns different. I would guess that this error is coming from a duplicate insert error somewhere else in your code, maybe one where you are specifying the value of the owner_id rather than letting the sequence increment it for you.

Comment: @Alba, also Serial4 will start at 1 and increment by 1, so I suspect you are are running more than one insert statement with the owner_id of 0 which would generate this error.